# Which is more valuable: a basket of optimal stopping problems or an optimal stopping problem on a basket?

Tags: volatility, stopping-time, dispersion

Fidelity now offers direct indexing for individuals for 40 bps per year, as well as zero-fee total market index funds. Which one should I dollar cost average (I.e., invest $x every n-th month) in? Does the problem boil down to an average correlation / dispersion  parameter?
Ignore the tax benefits of direct indexing. I would appreciate any references.

Comment: To my knowledge the advantage of direct indexing is the tax savings from "harvesting" capital losses. If you ignore this tax benefit I am not sure there is anything left to analyze.